# Serializing form submitted values on app engine

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I simply wanted to serialize all the fields of a submitted form, like this in PHP:

```
json_encode($_GET)
```

`json.dumps(self.request.get)` doesn't work:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: <bound method Request.get of <Request at 77ea190 GET http://localhost:8083/?a=value>> is not JSON serializable 
      args = ('<bound method Request.get of <Request at 77ea190...ocalhost:8083/?a=value>> is not JSON serializable',) 
      message = '<bound method Request.get of <Request at 77ea190...ocalhost:8083/?a=value>> is not JSON serializable'
```

I've tried using the CGI module and that too gives a not serializable error. I case you wondering: I use this to send data back to my template to repopulate the form fields.

Comment: It would make much more sense to URLEncode these parameters than to JSON encode them - in which case you can just get them in their original form with `self.request.query`.

Comment: @NickJohnson
I would do that if I wasn't using the jQuery Plugin called Populate. It takes care of every thing for me; it just wants a JSON string of the form contents. It's very handy: http://tinyurl.com/lmblvv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.request.get` returns the `get` method, not what the methods return. You have to do this:

```
json.dumps(self.request.GET.items())
```

`request.GET` will return a `UnicodeMultiDict` object, and `request.GET.items()` will return a list of tuples, each tuples being `(key, value`).

Cf. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html and http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id1